# Getting apache to use ldap group and filesystem group information

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, ldap, authorization, groups

We have an Apache server which serves out of a particular directory, and just supplies a listing of files.  From this directory, each subdirectory is owned by a certain group of users (at the filesystem level).  User groups are determined by a posixGroup in ldap.

Is there any simple way I can tell Apache to authorize access based on filesystem permissions, just like if the users were to access the filesystem from a shell?  I would like to be able to simply add users/groups/directories without having to add another Directory or Location directive in Apache's conf?